# Appium TouchActions not registering for WebGL Game in Selenium

Tags: javascript, ios, selenium, touch, appium

I have a simple javascript game (created with cocos2d-html5) that runs using WebGL / Canvas.  I'm able to simulate user interaction for desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox) using x,y coordinate clicks etc, however when I try to use Selenium (Java) and Appium's TouchActions for iphone testing, it doesn't register a single tap or press.

There is a start screen for mobile to capture user input for audio etc to work, clickable anywhere - and nothing I do triggers the screen.  Users are able to interact using mobile devices, so I know the screen works.  It appears that it's just the touch actions that aren't working, or I'm doing it wrong.

Appium driver setup is:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = getCapabilities();
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub");
driver = new AppiumDriver(url, capabilities);
```

I've tried:

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
touchAction.press(PointOption.point(200, 200))                 
           .waitAction(WaitOptions.waitOptions(Duration.ofMillis(100)))
           .release()
           .perform();
```

and

```
TouchAction touchAction = new TouchAction((PerformsTouchActions) driver);
TapOptions tapOptions = TapOptions.tapOptions()
    .withElement(ElementOption.element(gameCanvas()))
    .withPosition(PointOption.point(100, 100));
touchAction.tap(tapOptions);
```

where `gameCanvas()` returns `driver.findElement(By.id("gameCanvas"));`

I see the following Appium log output that seems relevant, but it's pretty noisy, and I'm not sure what else to look for:

```
[XCUITest] Executing command 'performTouch'
[XCUITest] Received the following touch action: tap(options={"x":187,"y":179})
[XCUITest] Found matching gesture: tap
[JSONWP Proxy] Proxying [POST /wda/tap/0] to [POST http://localhost:8100/session/F4AF63A8-89F0-4ECD-832E-8F4D3BB27001/wda/tap/0] with body: {"x":187,"y":179}
[JSONWP Proxy] Got response with status 200: {"value":{},"sessionId":"F4AF63A8-89F0-4ECD-832E-8F4D3BB27001","status":0}
[MJSONWP] Responding to client with driver.performTouch() result: null
```

Am I missing something?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How do you create instance of driver for mobile device? Share the code and capabilities you are using, also Appium server log will be helpful

Comment: I added driver initialization and some of the relevant log output, but there's way too much log to post in a question - Is there something in particular I should be looking for?